# Find a and b given $(3x + 2)$ and $(x - 2)$ are factors of $6x^3 + ax^2 - 4ax + b$.

Tags: polynomials, education

$(3x + 2)$ and $(x - 2)$ are factors of $6x^3 + ax^2 - 4ax + b$.
Find a and b.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Use the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) and set $f(2)=f(-\frac23)=0$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 2):

Multiply $(3x+2)(x-2)(2x+r)$ out.  Then equate and solve for a and b.

Comment: please expand and show how, where did $(2x+r)$ came from?

Comment: $6x^3+3rx^2-8x^2-4rx-8x-4r$.  

3r-8 =a is one of the equations

Comment: The three binomials multiplied should equal $6x^3\ldots$ so there should be a $2x$ to complement $3x$ and $x$. The "r" is just to complete the last linear factor with some variable.

Answer (score 1):

As  J. W. Tanner
wrote,
putting $x = 2$ gives
$6x^3 + ax^2 - 4ax + b
=6 8 + 4a - 8a + b
=b-4a+48
= 0
$
so
$4a-b = 48
$.

Putting $x = -\frac23$ gives
$6x^3 + ax^2 - 4ax + b
=-6 \frac{8}{27} + \frac49 a +\frac83 a + b
=- \frac{16}{9} + \frac{28}{9} a + b
$
so
$28a+9b = 16
$.

$28a-7b = 48\ 7 = 336
$
so
$16b = -320,
b = -20
$,
$a = (48+b)/4
=7
$.

And,
according to Wolfy,
$$\frac {6x^3 + 7x^2 - 28x -20}{(3x+2)(x-2)}
=2x+5
$$.

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$f(x)=6x^3 + ax^2 - 4ax + b=(3x + 2)(x - 2)(2x-r)$$

Set

$$f(0)= b=4r,\>\>\>\>\> f(4)=384+b=28(8-r)$$

to get $b=-20$ and $r=-5$. As a result

$$f(1)= -3a-14=-35\implies a=7$$